# Can I use a software tool licensed with GPL in commercial software development?

Tags: licensing

The question is specific to **using these tools to develop** commercial software.

The source or the binaries of the GPL licensed tool **does not** become part of the commercial software in anyway.

I do not want to modify the GPL licensed tool.

For example, an C/C++ development IDE that is licensed under GPL. Can I use this IDE to develop commercial software?

Other specific examples of tools I'd like to use are: Doxygen, Eclipse, etc.

Comment: Sure you can. All programs written for Apple's iOS and OSX use GPL compilers because that's what XCode uses

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: yes.

From Gnu Faq[1](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#CanIUseGPLToolsForNF)

> Can I use GPL-covered editors such as GNU Emacs to develop non-free
>   programs?
>
> ```
> Yes, because the copyright on the editors and tools
> ```
>
> does not cover the code you write. Using them does not place any restrictions,
>   legally, on the license you use for your code.
>
> ```
> Some programs copy parts of themselves into the output for technical reasons
> ```
>
> —for example, Bison copies a standard parser program
>   into its output file. In such cases, the copied text in the output is
>   covered by the same license that covers it in the source code.
>   Meanwhile, the part of the output which is derived from the program's
>   input inherits the copyright status of the input.
>
> ```
> As it happens, Bison can also be used to develop non-free programs.
> ```
>
> This is because we decided to explicitly permit the use of
>   the Bison standard parser program in Bison output files without
>   restriction. We made the decision because there were other tools
>   comparable to Bison which already permitted use for non-free programs.

Answer (score 2):

The GPL allows that. However, some programs or libraries may include additional restrictions. So, I think you can't answer it generally for all programs that are under GPL.

Doxygen and Eclipse are OK, though.